# How get Time picker django form (Template)

Tags: django, forms, timepicker

How get Time picker django form. 
Here is my code.
Thank you

My model:

```
    class activite(models.Model):
        jour = models.ForeignKey('jour',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jour' )
        debut = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        fin = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My form:

```
class activiteForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = fdt_activite
        fields = ('jour','debut','fin')
```

My template:

```
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Création activité</button>
    </form>

    <script>
    $('#debut').datetimepicker({
       showSecond: true,
       showMillisec: true,
       timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#debut') <- This id is incorrect
```

You've to pass the actual id of the `debut` field here.

Django automatically creates id for form fields like this: `id_<field-name>`. So, the id for `debut` field will be `id_debut`.

To fix it, use that in your JS:

```
$('#id_debut')
```

Comment: I added the JS: $ ('# id_debut') but no change.
Do I have to referecence like this example?
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @Bak Well, you'll also have to include the required JS files. Read the docs of the plugin that you're using. I'm sure it must have a nice explanation about setting things up.